# Selenium, problema con expected_conditions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Me encuentro realizando WebScrapping, y al usar las expected_conditions de selenium me salta un error diciendo que estoy pasando dos argumentos en vez de uno. Pero en todos lados la gente pasa 2 argumentos os dejo mi código a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.
Muchas gracias.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

driver_path ="C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Proyectospy\\Extraccion\\chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(driver_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)


driver.get('https://gestiona3.madrid.org/wpad_pub/run/j/MostrarConsultaGeneral.icm')

WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID ,'irBuscador'))\
.click()
```

Mensaje de error: presence_of_element_located() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad `EC.presence_of_element_located(arg)` está esperando un solo argumento. [Ver documentación](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). Como estás usando `By`, ese argumento se le pasa como una tupla. Observar el doble paréntesis `()` dentro de `presence_of_element_located`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID ,'irBuscador')))\
.click()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, vaya tontearía era lo siento.